# Does such property overriding work in Maven3?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I've got a parent pom.xml with build/pluginManagement/plugins/plugin section for `maven-compiler-plugin`. It contains configuration that's relies on property `${targetJdk}`, which is defined in parent pom as well.

And I've got a child pom.xml, which uses `maven-compiler-plugin` from parent.
But the child pom.xml overrides `${targetJdk}` property with other value.

Parent:

```
<properties>
    <targetJdk>1.8</targetJdk>
</properties>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${targetJdk}</source>
                    <target>${targetJdk}</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>       
</build>
```

Child:

```
<properties>
    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So the question is: when I build a child artifact, what property value will it use?

Comment: It will use `<targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>`.

Comment: I expect it too. Did you check this?

Comment: Why does the child override it?

Comment: I've got lots of child modules, almost all use JDK1.8, but some 1.7. So I want to override property for these ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you declare the same plugin and/or properties in a child pom, you override the parent.

Your child will use `<targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

for certainty always use the effective Pom

help:effective-pom